# Can't use SQLite Default while onCreate

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

i am having a issue with the Android SQLite Database.
I want to set some default values, when i create the database with onCreate().
The database gets created but the table is empty.

> ```
> //Datenbank anlegen
> private static final String CREATETABLE_SETTINGS =
>         "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SETTINGS + " (\n" +
>                 "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,\n" +
>                 "level TEXT DEFAULT 'hard',\n" +
>                 "design TEXT DEFAULT 'dark',\n" +
>                 "sound INTEGER DEFAULT '1',\n" +
>                 "music INTEGER DEFAULT '1',\n" +
>                 "vibration INTEGER DEFAULT '1',\n" +
>                 "control INTEGER DEFAULT '1');" ;
> ```

I don't know why the default values aren't working.

Thanks for every answer and excuse my bad language.

Comment: Post your code to set the default values..

Comment: And post any logcat/stacktrace when you are creating the database on device/emulator.

Comment: The code you have posted only creates the table itself.  It does not insert any data into the table.

Comment: Firstly remove the '\n' after every column, second you have given String as input to Integer fields so its not getting inserted. Correct query :     "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_SETTINGS + " (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
                "level TEXT DEFAULT 'hard'," +
                "design TEXT DEFAULT 'dark'," +
                "sound INTEGER DEFAULT 1," +
                "music INTEGER DEFAULT 1," +
                "vibration INTEGER DEFAULT 1," +
                "control INTEGER DEFAULT 1)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DEFAULT` in a column definition is only applied if no or a null value is supplied for a column when inserting or updating rows. The code you posted does not insert any rows.

To insert a row with default values, consider

```
"INSERT INTO " + TABLE_SETTINGS + "(id) VALUES(NULL)"
```

(You need to specify at least one column when inserting.)

Comment: This was the solution. Didn't insert something. Thought at least one column would be added automatically. @Ranjith: Your tip was right to.